# Does my simple proof work?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

From Hammack Book of Proof 4.12:

If $x$ is a real and $0<x<4$,  then `$\displaystyle\frac{4}{x(4-x)}\geq 1$.

Proof:

Since $x(4-x)$ is always positive, I can multiply it on both sides to get:

$$x(4-x)\leq 4 \iff 4x-x^2\leq 4 \iff 4x-x^2-4\leq 0.$$

Refactor, we get

$$-(x-2)^2 \leq 0$$

Since `$(x-2)^2$ is always positive,  $-(x-2)^2$ is always negative.

Thus, $-(x-2)^2 \leq 0$

Comment: You are absolutely fine but you can directly start from the given condition as well. I feel that would be much better.

Comment: @Rohan  What would 'starting from the initial condition' look like?

Comment: Can I post it as an answer?

Comment: You would go backwards from the proof you present: Start with the result: -(x-2)^2 <= 0 and then derive the fact that 4/(x(4-x)) >= 1. The proof you presented is a bit less clear because your proof starts with the assumption that the hypothesis is correct, and then get to a result. Generally speaking, this is "bad form" for proofs. It sort of works here, because you show that it infers a tautology, but it's better to go the reverse route. An alternative would be assume the statement false: i.e., assume 4/(x(4-x)) < 1 and show that this generates a contradiction of x is real and 0 < x < 4.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why is x(x-4) always positive? 1(1-4) = -3

Comment: I do not see any problem of form. The successive inequalities in the OP's argument are equivalent, meaning that they are either all true or all false. (Perhaps this logical equivalence should be stated explicitly in the proof.) Since the last one is clearly true, the first one is true as well.

Comment: @PrinceM You're right, it's x(4-x) that's positive. This is what's actually used in the proof. This should be edited.

Comment: @BillProvince Ah thanks.  That makes sense.  This chapter is on direct proofs.  I see how rewriting it, reversed, makes clearer sense then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we have $0 < x < 4$, we can see that $(x-2)^2 \geq 0$. Thus, $$x^2-4x+4 \geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow 4 \geq 4x-x^2 = x(4-x)$$ $$\frac{4}{x(4-x)} \geq 1.$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah that reads much more clearly. I think I've written a lot of my proofs 'backwards' in this respect.

Comment: @Rohan Yes, it's clearer, but from where did you pluck $(x-2)^2 \geq 0$?

Comment: It's very obvious, isn't it?